# Getting LedFx to activate when music is played by a cron job

Tags: linux, cron, pulseaudio

I have been using `LedFx` to sync leds to music from `pulseaudio` for about a year and it works great. Once `LedFx` is running the simple command `aplay music.wav` makes my `ESP32` controlled led strips come alive. However, when the same command is executed as a cron job (and as the same user) the music plays but the the lights do nothing even though `LedFx` is running. I have also tried using:`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/500" & export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH-"/run/user/$id -u)/pulse"` in front of the cron command. Any ideas how I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this useful I solved this by using the perl module: `Schedule::Cron` to run the command instead of crontab.